# How to check mongodb connection status?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, monitoring

How do I check if `mongodb` is still up from within Meteor? I tried (on the server) to stop `mongodb` and then write to a collection and read the record again, that works even if `mongodb` is not connected.

Problem is (on a self-hosted app) if the mongodb crashes the app does not throw an error, but there is no data. I would like to display an error message in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a document at startup and check whether it exists.

Meteor will poll all collections on a regular basis. If the database dies, the control document will be empty and this should trigger a ´removed´ event on the collection.

```
  var control = Meteor.Collection("control-doc");
  Meteor.startup(function () {
     control.remove({}); 
     control.insert({text: "just to fill"});
     control.find().observe({
        removed: function(old) {
           //send an alert
           console.log("alert");
        }
     })
  });
```

it is not the nicest of tricks but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Meteor.status()? Returns a reactive object with connection status stuff.

Comment: That is the connection to the client, not to the database.

Comment: Ah, missunderstood the question, sorry.